# Loading Question and Answers in KB From file hierarchy In qna maker

Tags: azure-qna-maker

Good Afternoon.

I'm a begginer with QnA maker, and I am evaluating it for making a FAQ chat bot. I already have created a KB and populated some values manually.

On a particular moment I came upon this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation#create-a-multi-turn-conversation-from-documents-structure

Particularly in the Create a multi-turn conversation from a document's structure paragraph it says:

" When you select this option, QnA Maker extracts the hierarchy present in the document structure. The hierarchy is converted in to follow up prompts and the root of the hierarchy serves as the parent QnA. In some documents the root of the hierarchy does not have content which could serve as an answer, you can provide the 'Default Answer Text' to be used as a substitute answer text to extract such hierarchies."

Then, I think it is, based on doc structure, able to create a set of questions and answers. So I thought What wonderful news!.... Until I tested it.

I have done test that with pdf, docx and txt, Using different font sizes for doc levels and plain text. But I get the same error every time.

"Bad Argument
Failed to extract QnAs from the source http://localhost/test.txt - Unsupported / Invalid url(s). Failed to extract Q&A from the source, http://localhost/test..txt - Unsupported / Invalid url(s). Failed to extract Q&A from the source, http://localhost/test.txt - Unsupported / Invalid url(s). Failed to extract Q&A from the source"

I think I must do something wrong. Url are locals http://localhost/test.txt , http://localhost/test.pdf, http://localhost/test.docx ... I can see the file from chrome and edge too, so I do not think the url is wrong, but the error still appears after several tests.

Anybody could kindly support me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The URL is invalid to the QnA API, because it must be accessible in a public URL and not a local one, like how you're attempting.

Notice how in the [multi-turn QnA Maker tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation#create-a-multi-turn-conversation-from-documents-structure) that you link, the [example document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-sample-data-files/blob/master/qna-maker/data-source-formats/product-manual.pdf) that they provide regarding Surface Pro 4 is actually uploaded to GitHub, where it can be accessed publicly.

So to use your own document, simply upload it to someplace online where the QnA API can access it to seed your KB.